# How to update text of label in timer_Tick in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, label, nfc

In my winforms C# project I have a NFC device which is connected to pc and works properly.I have this part of code in Timer_Tick

```
   private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (NFC.Connect())
                //label6.Text = "دستگاه متصل میباشد";
                label6.Text = "device is connected";
            label6.Invalidate();
            label6.Update();
            Application.DoEvents();


        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            label6.Text = "device is not connected";
            //label6.Text = "دستگاه متصل نمی باشد";
            label6.Invalidate();
            label6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            label6.Update();
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

    }
```

I want to show the device is connected or not but the problem is that  label6.text does not update.
Can anyone help please?

Comment: and the Tick event does fire?

Comment: @rene yes when i disconnect nfc the catch body will execute and text value of label will update but when i connect nfc device again it wont update

Comment: Okay. So NFC.Connect doesn't return true then when nfc is connected. The problem is in that code, not in the stuff you show. You can remove the Appliction.DoEvents, and the calls to Update and Invalidate. You don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using this library; https://github.com/h4kbas/nfc-reader/blob/master/NFCReader.cs

Then perhaps you should have a code like:

```
    try
    {
        if (NFC.Connect())
            label6.Text = "device is connected " + DateTime.Now;
        else
            label6.Text = "device didn't connect " + DateTime.Now;

        label6.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        label6.Text = "device error " + e.Message;
        label6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

I'd suggest also renaming label6 to something more apt, like `statusLabel`. Always rename your controls

---

Re your comment, here is the code of Connect()

```
ublic bool Connect()
    {
        string readerName = GetReadersList()[0];
        connActive = true;
        retCode = Card.SCardConnect(hContext, readerName, Card.SCARD_SHARE_SHARED,
                             Card.SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 | Card.SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1, ref hCard, ref Protocol);
        if (retCode != Card.SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
        {
            connActive = false;
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
```

You claim "it's connected but Caius code says it's not" -> Caius' code only goes off whether the library says it is connected or not. If Caius' code says it is not connected when it is, it's not Caius' code fault.. Library is open source; go fix the code of it for others to benefit

Comment: yes this is same library i checked your code it displays device didnt connect while nfc is connected to pc

Comment: It's not connected, or library is not telling the truth. Look at library code